# increment values in column within file with bash, sed and awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Please find below an excerpt from one of my file.

```
1991;1;-7;-3;-9;-4;-7
1991;1;-7;-3;-9;-4;-7
1991;1;-7;-3;-9;-4;-7
1991;2;-14;-11;-14;-4;-14
1991;2;-14;-11;-14;-4;-14
1991;2;-14;-11;-14;-4;-14
1991;3;-7;-3;-15;5;-7
1991;3;-7;-3;-15;5;-7
1991;3;-7;-3;-15;5;-7
1991;4;-15;-9;-21;1;-16
1991;4;-15;-9;-21;1;-16
1991;4;-15;-9;-21;1;-16
1992;1;-12;-6;-19;-2;-12
1992;1;-12;-6;-19;-2;-12
1992;1;-12;-6;-19;-2;-12
1992;2;-16;-7;-22;-12;-15
1992;2;-16;-7;-22;-12;-15
1992;2;-16;-7;-22;-12;-15
1992;3;-22;-15;-25;-16;-24
1992;3;-22;-15;-25;-16;-24
```

I'm trying through sed or/and awk to add + 1 on the second column for the second row for the second row as long as the year in the first column remains the same.

The results would be the following:

```
1991;1;-7;-3;-9;-4;-7
1991;2;-7;-3;-9;-4;-7
1991;3;-7;-3;-9;-4;-7
1991;4;-14;-11;-14;-4;-14
1991;5;-14;-11;-14;-4;-14
1991;6;-14;-11;-14;-4;-14
1991;7;-7;-3;-15;5;-7
1991;8;-7;-3;-15;5;-7
1991;9;-7;-3;-15;5;-7
1991;10;-15;-9;-21;1;-16
1991;11;-15;-9;-21;1;-16
1991;12;-15;-9;-21;1;-16
1992;1;-12;-6;-19;-2;-12
1992;2;-12;-6;-19;-2;-12
1992;3;-12;-6;-19;-2;-12
1992;4;-16;-7;-22;-12;-15
1992;5;-16;-7;-22;-12;-15
1992;6;-16;-7;-22;-12;-15
1992;7;-22;-15;-25;-16;-24
1992;8;-22;-15;-25;-16;-24
```

I've seen countless examples on stackflow but nothing that can lead me close to a solution.

I welcome any suggestions.

Best,

Comment: edit lines with the first year (1991) in the file?

Comment: hi, I'm not sure to understand ...

Comment: edit all years or just one year?

Comment: all years, suspectus. I was thinking of using a FOR loop , which would be parsing for the year and then use "awk -F\| '{++$2;print}'"

Comment: Why list specific tools (sed, awk) when you don't actually care about which tool is used, or have reason to believe any particular tool to be appropriate for the use case? If you want a solution using standard shell tools, specify "standard shell tools" rather than assuming that specific tools will fit the problem.

Comment: I'm more familiar with SED and AWK. This is the reason I quote them. If bash can do the trick, I'm happy with it.

Comment: We have people coming into #bash all the time asking "how do I do X with sed?", and on investigation it turns out that sed is a horrible fit for their problem and they should be using the shell's built-in parameter expansion, or an external tool such as XMLStarlet, or some other random thing they didn't know about. Narrowing down your question's range of possible answers to disallow things you didn't know about before you asked prevents learning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you always want the 2nd column to be 1 for the line in which the year first appears in column 1, then:

```
awk -F\; '$1!=l{c=0}{$2=++c}{l=$1}1' OFS=\; input
```

If you want to maintain whatever was in column 2:

```
awk -F\; '$1!=l{c=$2}{$2=c++}{l=$1}1' OFS=\; input
```

Comment: +1, terseness. I normally prefer readability, but it's good to have a proper answer showing awk's strengths.

Answer (score 4):

This could be done more tersely with awk, but pure bash works fine:

```
last_year=
counter_val=
while IFS=';' read -r year old_counter rest; do
  if [[ $year = "$last_year" ]]; then
    (( ++counter_val ))
  else
    counter_val=1
    last_year=$year
  fi
  printf -v result '%s;' "$year" "$counter_val" "$rest"
  printf '%s\n' "${result%;}"
done <input.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: Charles, I've tried your command line but it does not work ...

It gives me "non valid arithmetical error" when running the while loop.

Comment: @AndyK, that's not an error message that actually exists anywhere in bash. Are you sure you copied it correctly? Also, are you sure your script actually starts with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`? (If you had a script starting with `#!/bin/bash` but you ran it with `sh scriptname`, that would cause the same problem)

Comment: @AndyK, Ooh. Did find a bug there -- needed quotes around the IFS value. Try again now, with `IFS=';'` rather than `IFS=;`.

Comment: I've tried it without putting it in a shell script. Let me try again within a proper shell script. Thanks for your feedback, Charles.

Comment: This is what I have after running in a bash shell 

`./test_toto.sh < toto2_rev.csv > toto3_rev.csv
./test_toto.sh: line 6: ((: Ann▒e: erreur de syntaxe : opérateur arithmétique non valable (error token is "▒e")
./test_toto.sh: line 6: ((: Ann▒e: erreur de syntaxe : opérateur arithmétique non valable (error token is "▒e")
./test_toto.sh: line 6: ((: Libell▒: erreur de syntaxe : opérateur arithmétique non valable (error token is "▒")
`

Comment: @AndyK A few notes: (1) `export LC_ALL=C` will provide 7-bit-clean English-language messages; (2) Does this happen for you against the test data you provided in the question, or only with production data you haven't disclosed?

Comment: ...in any case, I changed the year comparison from a math operation to a string operation, which should moot the issue of the data containing years which are not numeric in nature. Still, I strongly suspect that this was an issue of non-representative test data.

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for your feedback and great healp. I checked it again after the weekend , mental unload necessary.

The issue was due to the header in french. After removing it, the bash script did what it was supposed to do , perfectly.

Thank you again for your help, I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You simply want to increment your second column, and not add one to it? Do you want the second column to go from one onward no matter what the second column is?

```
awk -F\; '{
    if ( NR == 1 ) {
        year = $0
    }
    if ( year == $0 ) {
        for (count = 1; count < NF; count++) {
            if ( count == 2) {
                printf NR ";";
            }
            else {
                printf $count ";";
            }
        }
        print "";
    }
    else {
        print 
    }
}' test.txt
```

Awk is a natural program to use because it operates in assuming a loop. Plus, it's math is more natural than plain shell.

The `NR` means *Number of Records* and `NF` means *Number of fields*. A field is separated by my `-F\;` parameter, and the record is the line number in my file. The rest of the program is pretty obvious.

Comment: Good answer, but I disagree somewhat with the commentary -- since the shell specified is bash, it has perfectly natural integer math; as long as you're in a math context (with `(( ))`), you have all the same operators C does -- even the ternary. The same mostly applies to ksh and POSIX sh, except with the need to use `$(( ))` in the latter; it's been a long time since integer math was awful in shell.

Comment: David, the test.txt is the input file. Am I correct with my guess?

Comment: Yes. I grabbed your data and put it in a file called `text.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Checking again.

Comment: I tried again with my files and also with the excerpt in a file but it is not functionning...

Answer (score 1):

Using awk, set the `FS` (field separator) and `OFS` (output field separator) to ';' and 
for each new year record set the val counter to the start column 2 value. Increment `val` for each line with that year.

```
awk -F';' 'BEGIN{OFS=";";y=0} 
 { if (y!=$1) 
      {y=$1;val=$2;print} 
   else 
      {val++;print $1,val,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}}' data_file
```

Comment: your solution is working fine , Suspectus. Many thanks for being the first to answer.

Comment: Given all the other answers I have to thank you for verifying it worked! :)

Comment: Always, Suspectus, always. I value your work and the ones of the other contributors and I'm learning. No work is like a drop of water in the rain , it is a single and unique. ;)